# k3s - Metrics server doesn't work for worker nodes

Tags: kubernetes, k3s, metrics-server

I deployed a k3s cluster into 2 raspberry pi 4. One as a master and the second as a worker using the script k3s offered with the following options:

For the master node:

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | INSTALL_K3S_EXEC='server --bind-address 192.168.1.113 (which is the master node ip)' sh -
```

To the agent node:

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | \
                K3S_URL=https://192.168.1.113:6443 \
                K3S_TOKEN=<master-token> \
                INSTALL_K3S_EXEC='agent' sh-
```

Everything seems to work, but `kubectl top nodes` returns the following:

```
NAME          CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%     
k3s-master    137m         3%     1285Mi          33%         
k3s-node-01   <unknown>                           <unknown>               <unknown>               <unknown>
```

I also tried to deploy the k8s dashboard, according to what is written in [the docs](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/kube-dashboard/) but it fails to work because it can't reach the metrics server and gets a timeout error:

```
"error trying to reach service: dial tcp 10.42.1.11:8443: i/o timeout"
```

and I see a lot of errors in the pod logs:

```
2021/09/17 09:24:06 Metric client health check failed: the server is currently unable to handle the request (get services dashboard-metrics-scraper). Retrying in 30 seconds.
2021/09/17 09:25:06 Metric client health check failed: the server is currently unable to handle the request (get services dashboard-metrics-scraper). Retrying in 30 seconds.
2021/09/17 09:26:06 Metric client health check failed: the server is currently unable to handle the request (get services dashboard-metrics-scraper). Retrying in 30 seconds.
2021/09/17 09:27:06 Metric client health check failed: the server is currently unable to handle the request (get services dashboard-metrics-scraper). Retrying in 30 seconds.
```

logs from the `metrics-server` pod:

```
elet_summary:k3s-node-01: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet k3s-node-01 (k3s-node-01): Get https://k3s-node-01:10250/stats/summary?only_cpu_and_memory=true: dial tcp 192.168.1.106:10250: connect: no route to host
E0917 14:03:24.767949       1 manager.go:111] unable to fully collect metrics: unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:k3s-node-01: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet k3s-node-01 (k3s-node-01): Get https://k3s-node-01:10250/stats/summary?only_cpu_and_memory=true: dial tcp 192.168.1.106:10250: connect: no route to host
E0917 14:04:24.767960       1 manager.go:111] unable to fully collect metrics: unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:k3s-node-01: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet k3s-node-01 (k3s-node-01): Get https://k3s-node-01:10250/stats/summary?only_cpu_and_memory=true: dial tcp 192.168.1.106:10250: connect: no route to host
```

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this behaviour (not on raspberry but on ubuntu VMs), after some time passed, worker node get metrics as well. I see that your commands to install a bit different to [documentation says](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/quick-start/#install-script). You can also try to restart the metric server by `k3s kubectl rollout restart deploy metrics-server -n kube-system` + check logs in `metrics-server` pod.

Comment: thanks, added logs from metrics-server pod, and it seens like it's looking in the wrong IP of the node?

Comment: There's something wrong set up in the network. Can you ping by `hostname` your worker node? Check `/etc/hosts` if there's an entry or try to add it with the correct IP.

Comment: after fixing `/etc/hosts` and rolling, I still see the same errors of `dial tcp: i/o timeout`

Comment: Well, this is a different error. This time it looks like your network see the another host. 1 - Can you ping/curl another host from the system? Does it work? 2 - Check `sudo netstat -tulpn` on worker node, does it listen on 10250? 3 - Are any firewalls on hosts? If so, disable it for test.

Comment: I re-provisioned the cluster and everything seems to be working now. Part of the problem was ntp not working so I had cert issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving this out of comments for better visibility.

---

After creation of small cluster, I wasn't able to reproduce this behaviour and `metrics-server` worked fine for both nodes, `kubectl top nodes` showed information and metrics about both available nodes (thought it took some time to start collecting the metrics).

Which leads to troubleshooting steps why it doesn't work. Checking `metrics-server` logs is the most efficient way to figure this out:

```
$ kubectl logs metrics-server-58b44df574-2n9dn -n kube-system
```

Based on logs it will be different steps to continue, for instance in comments above:

- first it was `no route to host` which is related to network and lack of possibility to resolve hostname
- then `i/o timeout` which means route exists, but service did not respond back. This may happen due to firewall which blocks certain ports/sources, `kubelet` is not running (listens to port `10250`) or as it appeared for OP, there was an issue with `ntp` which affected certificates and connections.
- errors may be different in other cases, it's important to find the error and based on it troubleshoot further.